# Rails 5 - How to use postgresql query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting

In rails 5, I am using `pg`(postgresql) for a back-end database. Now I want to query through rails and get the data. How can I use `IN` and `ORDER(:created_at, :desc)` conditions in a query.

In controller,

```
PAGE_LIMIT = 5
posts = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", [1,2,3]).order(created_at: :desc)
posts = posts.paginate(params[:page], PAGE_LIMIT)
```

I am writing a custom method like,

```
def paginate(page, limit = 5)
  page = page ? page.to_i : 1
  limit = limit.to_i
  offset = (page - 1) * limit
  self.offset(offset).limit(limit)
end
```

I am new to postgresql. Please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Shruthi R in any case you can share your code so that i can help you to get what exactly you want, i think the answer given below will help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you have `User` model and you want to get user which has `id` in `[1,2,3]`

```
User.where("id IN (?)", [1,2,3]).order(created_at: :desc)
```

for more dynamic

```
x = [1,2,3] 
name = "testing123"
User.where("name = ? AND id IN (?)", name, x).order(created_at: :desc)
```

for more details you can see [Active Record Query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

to make it working with pagination for array changes to be done here

**modified answer**

```
PAGE_LIMIT = 5
posts_arr = Post.where("user_id IN (?)", [1,2,3]).order(created_at: :desc)
posts = Post.where(id: posts_arr.map(&:id)) #here to get active records of posts to make it working for custom pagination
posts = posts.paginate(params[:page], PAGE_LIMIT)
```

Comment: How about just `User.where(id: x).order(created_at: :desc)` or `User.where(id: x, name: name).order(created_at: :desc)`? Seems cleaner and more idiomatic, IMO.

Comment: Yeah its cleaner code but i was just explaning how to use IN thats why i used  id in ..

Comment: Fair enough, and nicely done. Do you mind if I edit it into your answer?

Comment: This query will not take `paginate(params[:page]` and it throws an error like `undefined method 'paginate' for #<Array:0x007f4d41f95598> excluded from capture: DSN not set`. How can I paginate for the same?

Comment: @ShruthiR for array you will need to include this `require 'will_paginate/array'` to your controller or in application controller.

Comment: @ShruthiR try the modified answer that have been done for pagination i showed you an example.

Comment: @ShruthiR feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Yes definitely. First half is working fine but pagination part is not working. Could you please help in the same?

Comment: did you added `require 'will_paginate/array'` in your controller where you using pagination?

Comment: @ShruthiR why dn't you use `will_paginate` gem instead of custom pagination

Comment: But I have limitations to do that, I should use this custom method.

Comment: @ShruthiR so far as i got for you an alternative solution please check the answer.

Comment: @ShruthiR could you let me know if it helped you? or any feedback?